# Android : How to add a partial border?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android application in which I have a ListView for which I would like to add a border for each row in ListView. Generally adding a border shouldn't be a problem, but the border in design specifications is just half. How can I do that? Check out the screenshot :

[image]

As you can see the grey line, that is the border which is not touching end of the screen.

Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/conversationList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_default"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/trashImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
            android:src="@drawable/swappossible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/swapImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/trashImage"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/footerheart" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/swapImage"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="41dp"
            android:src="@drawable/footermessages" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Updated code**

Below is the code for individual rows in ListView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:background="@color/common_action_bar_splitter"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/seller"
                android:src="@drawable/perfume"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_image"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buyer"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/buyer"
                android:src="@drawable/mixer"

                android:background="@drawable/layout_image"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/uploader"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:id="@+id/swapButton"
                android:src="@drawable/swap_ready"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/uploader"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seller"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/seller" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/swapMessage"
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Hey! I&apos;d like to swap..."
                android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/uploaderName"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"

                android:text="Bridget"
                android:layout_below="@+id/uploader"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/uploader"
                android:src="@drawable/lena_round"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_above="@+id/swapMessage"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/uploaderName"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/uploaderName"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="10 minutes ago"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buyer"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buyer" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Morrison"
                android:id="@+id/uploaderLastName"
                android:gravity="center"

                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/uploaderName"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/uploaderName"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/uploaderName"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/uploaderName" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#555555"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you.

Comment: add a border (which is actually not a border, but a separator) a margin.

Comment: @VladMatvienko : Can you tell me what exactly you mean and how to accomplish it?

Comment: add a `View` to the bottom of your list item layout, set it's background color to required color, set it's height to the required height, set it's margins to required margins to required margins.

Comment: @VladMatvienko : Can you please share an example?

Comment: no, sorry, you have to do at least something by youself. If you have problems, tell me what exactly makes you a problem from the algorithm, I wrote above

Comment: @VladMatvienko : Point is, everything I have is in XML, then you said to add a View, what exactly do you mean by that, which View, there are views like WebView, CalendarView, ViewStub, etc? How is this going to help create a border is something still I am trying to figure out as I have not yet understood what you are saying.

Comment: `<View background="#555555" height="1dp" width="match_parent" margin="5dp"/>`. Place it in the bottom of your list item layout, and adjust color, margin, height, width...

Comment: @VladMatvienko Please post an answer, I had to reduce the margin, it works, but the border which I have shown in the screenshot is also there, now I can see both of them. Pasting updated code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122291/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and-vlad-matvienko).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a custom separator, you can add a View to the bottom of your list item xml:

```
<View background="#555555" height="1dp" width="match_parent" margin="5dp"/>
```

Adjust a color, size and margins for your requirements.

To remove a default system divider, use

```
<ListView
    android:divider="@null"
    ...
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following given below at the bottom of your list item layout.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#d7d7d7"/>
```

or you can use recylerview like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and please add the following in your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko  is it okay now

Comment: Good option, so upvoted, already used code by Vlad... Thank you.